# Does Gitlab comes with a windows client?

Tags: gitlab

Does gitlab has its own windows client or does it support any other compatible windows client ? if so, could you please help with the same.
Thnks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I use [msys2.org](http://www.msys2.org) and it works like a charm with GitHub, GitLab and BitBucket.

When you run the `msys2` console for the first time, issue:

```
pacman -Syu git
```

This will update the system and install a fresh copy of git.
 `pacman` is a powerful  package manager and you may discover more potentially interesting packages  with:

```
pacman -Ss <search string>
```

Note that git is a standard  for source control (like SVN). In so far as a service claims it is git based, it must work with a git client.   However, companies hosting the git server usually offer other services too: release repositories, continuous integration/delivery, wiki pages etc. These are not part of the git standard and therefore might require additional client software.